# Is there a way to get Hibernate's hbm2ddl Ant task to exclude specific tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, annotations, hbm2ddl

I use Hibernate to generate my database automatically for testing, and I have some tables in my schema that contain static data that takes a very long time to import. In the past, I've used the following code in my build file to generate the database (from mapping files):

```
<target name="schema-gen" depends="hibernate-gen">
    <taskdef name="schemaexport" classname="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExportTask" classpathref="project.classpath" />

    <schemaexport properties="resources/hibernate.properties" text="false" quiet="false" delimiter=";" output="schema.sql">
        <fileset dir="${build.doclets}">
            <include name="**/*.hbm.xml" />
            <exclude name="**/inert/*.hbm.xml" />
        </fileset>
    </schemaexport>
</target>
```

The .hbm.xml files were generated using XDoclet. I'm migrating to using Hibernate Annotations for mapping, so I'm moving to hibernatetools to generate the schema:

```
<target name="annotations-export" depends="hibernate-gen">
    <hibernatetool destdir="${basedir}">
        <annotationconfiguration configurationfile="${basedir}/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" propertyfile="${basedir}/resources/hibernate.properties" />
        <classpath>
            <path refid="project.classpath" />
        </classpath>
        <hbm2ddl drop="true" create="true" export="true" outputfilename="schema.sql" delimiter=";" format="true" />
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

I'd like to be able to tell hbm2ddl to leave out the classes in the "inert" package, just like I used to with schemaexport. Anyone know if there's a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I wound up going with was creating a separate Hibernate configuration with exactly the classes I wanted to map, and using that for the export task instead of the other Hibernate configuration with all of the mapped classes.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<target name="annotations-export" depends="hibernate-gen">
    <hibernatetool destdir="${basedir}">
        <annotationconfiguration configurationfile="${basedir}/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" propertyfile="${basedir}/resources/hibernate.properties">
            <fileset dir="${build.doclets}">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
                <exclude name="**/inert/*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </annotationconfiguration>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="project.classpath" />
        </classpath>
        <hbm2ddl drop="true" create="true" export="true" outputfilename="schema.sql" delimiter=";" format="true" />
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

Comment: This was a good idea, but it didn't work because I could never get the fileset to work quite right. Getting it to include exactly the files I wanted and not include those I didn't want was just too much work.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the *update* attribute on the *hbmddl* tag?

```
<hbm2ddl update="true" ...
```

see [here](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/ant.html#d0e1137) for the details

that should work

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I want to recreate most of the tables (to reset things for my tests), but I want to skip some tables. update will leave everything that exists intact, which isn't quite the behavior I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this situation and you happen to not want Hibernate to update the *data* in the tables either, then you can replace:

```
<class name="FooClass" table="FOO_TABLE"></class>
```

with

```
<class name="Foo" subselect="select * from FOO_TABLE">
  <synchronize table="FOO_TABLE">
</class>
```

then the schema export tool will ignore it, but so will any writes. At least, that's what the documentation suggests.

> subselect (optional): maps an immutable and read-only entity to a
>   database subselect.

I discovered this through looking at the `Table.isPhysicalTable` function.  You could also look into using AbstractUnionTables, which are the other exception.

I happen to want immutable objects.

My use case is that I want to load slightly differently shaped immutable editions of some hibernate managed objects without a risk of accidentally changing the schema export. So subselect is pretty well suited to that.

Unfortunately it will litter all your queries with that subselect, which the database *should* be able to optimize it away, but people have varying amounts of trust in database optimisation with good reason.

Comment: Apparently I tricked myself while testing this the first time.  Initially I tested with 

subselect="select * from table_name"

and checked that it didn't update the schema, and worked, and then I must have refined it to 

subselect="table_name"

and only checked that it worked.  Because testing again, just using subselect="table_name" still updates the schema. 

I'll update the answer to make this comment use the select from syntax, even though it's much uglier :(

Comment: I explored the other option, setting abstract="true".  That seems to work fine for my situation where I also have mutable="false".  I'll explore that more carefully before either updating this answer or adding another one, since it's different really.